# How to authenticate users from an oracle database using jdbc in spring security?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm a newbie with spring Mvc. I've created a `login.jsp` page and I want to authenticate users dynamically from database using spring security.

This is my spring security configuration:

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password" default-target-url="/accueil"
        authentication-failure-url="/403" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="userService">
        </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

And this is my userService:

```
@Component(value = "userService")
public class UserService implements AuthenticationProvider {
    @Inject
    @Named(value = "dataSource")
    private DataSource dataSource1;

    final String select_auth = "select username,password from users";

    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication auth) throws AuthenticationException {
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = dataSource1.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(select_auth);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                String name=resultSet.getString("username");
                String pwd =resultSet.getString("password");
                if (name.equals("what?")){
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (resultSet != null) {
                try {
                    resultSet.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                }
            }
            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                try {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                }
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                try {
                    connection.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                }
            }
        }

        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("", "");
    }

    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The connection to the database works, but my problem is how to get the inputs from `login.jsp` and test if the username and the password are the same in the database?

And what to return if the user exists in the database ?

Comment: Change your *final String select_auth = "select username,password from users"* to accept a parameter: the username. If the record exists you can also check the (encrypted / hashed) password. Once the check is completed you can return your token.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
but i didn't inderstood what parameters to add , and how to add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Username and password are stored within the **Authentication** object

```
    String username = auth.getName();
    String password = auth.getCredentials().toString();
```

so you can check them against your DB data (as I suggested in the comment).

```
    final String select_auth = "select username,password from users WHERE username=?"; // Use your prepared statement to bind the username
```

Once you get the record back (if exists) you can check the password using your PasswordEncoder (hopefully your password *is* encoded, e.g. encrypted / hashed). And then, e.g.

```
    return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(new MyUserDetails(username, password, ...), password); // There is also a constructor that accepts granted authorities
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! it helped me a lot :) last one thing .. after  cheking the username and the password ..if the record exists in the data base what to return (to give access to the user to the secured page)? i'm confused !

Comment: It's completely up to you. The *UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken* accepts two Objects: the first one is the *principal* object and then its *credentials* (also *granted authorities* if you have any). You can define your own principal and credentials (usually just the encoded password) classes. Working with Spring I'd suggest to implements the *UserDetails* interface for the principal. I have edited my answer.